# How can I run .sh file on MAC from other directory

Tags: macos, shell, terminal

I'm a new for Mac developing.

I try to create project.sh file and run it via Terminal

See [mac.zip](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7278978/Work/mac.zip) for more details.

The main class (com.myclass.MyClass) is in "main.jar" that requires lib1.jar, lib2.jar, and sublib1.jar

The "CLASSPATH" property in "project.sh" is created via script, it cannot be changed in project.sh

The value is always in relative path format such as "../../lib/lib1.jar"

When I try to run it from "mac/project" directory that contains main.jar and project.sh via Mac Terminal

It work fine as following

```
Gui-iMac:project gui$ ./project.sh
AClass
BClass
CClass
```

However, when I try to run project.sh from other directory, it failed.

For example: run from desktop directory:

```
Gui-iMac:desktop gui$ "/Users/gui/Desktop/GUI/Mac/project/project.sh"
Error: Could not find or load main class com.myclass.MyClass
```

How can I run project.sh from other directory?

Please help me to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

earist

Comment: in `/Users/gui/Desktop/GUI/Mac/project/project.sh`, add `cd $(dirname "$0")`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the answer that you are looking for but to run a .sh script from another directory you can use

```
$sh /Users/gui/Desktop/GUI/Mac/project/project.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Now, I find the solution for this problem.

using

> cd "$directoryName" && exec "$myCommand"

as following:

```
#!/bin/bash
BASE=$(dirname "$0")
ARGS=""

if [ $# -gt 1 ]; then
    while [ $# -ge 1 ]; do
        case "$1" in
            -[a-z]*) ARGS="$ARGS $1" ;;
            *) ARGS="$ARGS \"$1\"" ;;
        esac
        shift
    done
fi

CLASSPATH=.:../lib/lib1.jar:../lib/lib2.jar:./lib/sublib1.jar:./main.jar
JAVA_COMMAND=java
VM_OPTIONS="-Xmx800M"
EXEC_COMMAND="cd \"$BASE\" && exec $JAVA_COMMAND $VM_OPTIONS -cp $CLASSPATH com.myclass.MyClass $ARGS"
eval $EXEC_COMMAND
```